# How to work with block timestamps in ethers and hardhat?

Tags: hardhat, timestamp, mocha, chai, time

I have a time-dependent contract that has two require statements

```
    function launch(uint256 _goal, uint32 _startAt, uint32 _endAt) external {
        require(_startAt >= block.timestamp, "start at < now");
        require(
            _endAt >= _startAt + minDuration &&
                _endAt <= _startAt + maxDuration,
            "not in min & max duration"
        );

        count += 1;
        campaigns[count] = Campaign({
            id: count,
            creator: msg.sender,
            goal: _goal,
            pledged: 0,
            startAt: _startAt,
            endAt: _endAt,
            claimed: false,
            cancelled: false
        });

        emit Launch(count, msg.sender, _goal, _startAt, _endAt);
    }
```

I am testing the contract in hardhat and I am trying to test the condition that the campaign is too short (i.e. endAt < startAt + minDuration). However, I keep getting the error "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'start at < now'" instead of the "not in min & max duration" error.
In hardhat I am using the following code to test this condition:

```typescript
        it.only('should revert if campaign too short', async () => {
          blockTimestamp = (await ethers.provider.getBlock('latest')).timestamp;
          const endAt = blockTimestamp + (Number(minDuration) - 10);

          console.log(endAt); // 1676757538
          console.log(blockTimestamp); // 1676757518

          expect(
            await crowdfund.launch(campaignGoal, blockTimestamp, endAt)
          ).to.be.revertedWith('not in min & max duration');
        });
```

for reference `minDuration = ethers.BigNumber.from('30')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first `require` statement fails, because you are passing the `blockTimestamp` value to the `launch` function as `startAt`.

Try to test the condition where the campaign is too short by adding a few seconds to the current `blockTimestamp` to ensure the `startAt` is in the future:

```js
it.only('should revert if campaign too short', async () => {
  blockTimestamp = (await ethers.provider.getBlock('latest')).timestamp;
  const startAt = blockTimestamp + 10;
  const endAt = startAt + Number(minDuration) - 10;

  console.log(startAt);
  console.log(endAt);

  await expect(
    crowdfund.launch(campaignGoal, startAt, endAt)
  ).to.be.revertedWith('not in min & max duration');
});
```

Comment: thanks worked liked a charm!

Comment: glad that it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate time with this. 60*60*24 = 1 day.

```
    await hre.ethers.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [60 * 60 * 24])
    await hre.ethers.provider.send("evm_mine")
```

Comment: great thank you!